# Javascript flood fill algorithm getting caught in an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, flood-fill

Hello I am trying to implement a simple flood fill type algorithm in javascript. Basically I have a 3x3 board which I represent as a 1 dimensional array. I want to append the index for every equal value that is "touching" to a separate array. So for instance this board:

[1][1][0] 
[3][1][3] 
[0][0][0]

Would be represented as a 1D array ie [1,1,0,3,1,3,0,0,0]. And after running the floodFill on one of the [1] it would result with an array that looks like this [4, 1, 0] because those are the indexes in the 1d array that are touching, which have the same value.

Here is the code:

```
var boardArray = new Array(1,1,0,3,1,3,0,0,0);
var comboArray = new Array();
function floodFill(n, diceVal) {
    if(boardArray[n] != diceVal) {
        return;
    }
    comboArray.push(n);

    if (n >0 && n < 8) {
    // right
    if(!(n%3==2)) {
        floodFill(n+1, diceVal);
    }

    // left
    if(!(n%3==0)) {
        floodFill(n-1, diceVal);
    }

    // up
    if(n>2) {
        floodFill(n-3, diceVal);
    }

    // down
    if(n<5) {
        floodFill(n+3, diceVal);
    }
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
floodFill(4,1);
```

Can anyone tell me why this is getting stuck in an infinite loop?

Comment: In your "up" case, the first time through, you'll call `floodFill(1,1);`. *That* call, in its "down" case, will call `floodFill(4,1);`, which will soon call `floodFill(1,1)`...

Comment: Hint: if only there were some array where you could see which squares you'd already processed. Oh, wait...

Comment: This is what I thought I should do: Add an array which keeps track of all the index values on which flood fill has already been called, before calling flood fill check to see if the index has already been used, if so, return. But the flood fill algo on wikipedia makes no mention of this which is why I thought I was doing something wrong.

Comment: You're already tracking what you need. You just need to *check* it. See my answer below.

Comment: Without looking, if the flood fill algorithm on wikipedia was *changing* to the new color as it went along, this problem wouldn't occur. The next time you hit the same square, its color has changed and it no longer matches.

Comment: Ahhh yes exactly, ok thanks so much. I accepted your answer below. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "up" case, the first time through, you'll call `floodFill(1,1);`. That call, in its "down" case, will call `floodFill(4,1);`, which will soon call `floodFill(1,1)`

You're already keeping track of the matching squares - the only ones that will really cause any trouble. Just confirm that you're not checking the same square *again*:

```
function floodFill(n, diceVal) {
  if(boardArray[n] != diceVal) {
    return;
  }

  // have we been here before?
  if (comboArray.indexOf(n) >= 0)
    return;

  comboArray.push(n);

  // ...
}
```